# Calculating a main floor load bearing wall for 4 story condo

Tags: walls

I'm seeking help on calculations of a main flood load bearing wall support for our 4 story (basement and 3 floors) condo. The raw area of the condo is 19'6" wide by 27'6" deep. The full length of the existing wall is 15'6". The wall I am trying to calculate is shown in blue on the floor plan picture I have attached.

Thanks for any help
Brett

[image]

Comment: You say, “load bearing wall”. How do you know it’s load bearing? If it is, is it vertical loads, horizontal loads or both? I see one floor plan. Is wall aligned with other walls above or below?

Comment: Yes the wall is aligned with wall on the floor above and in the basement.

Comment: Vertical loads. The right side wall is shared with the unit next door. The left side wall is exterior. The top side wall is the front of the unit and the boxed area is a bathroom.

Comment: What Lee said ... how do you know it's load bearing?  If you look to the left of your marked area ... the gap between that rectangular space and the stairs.  What does that area look like at the ceiling.  If that wall is load bearing, then that passage should likely have a large header/beam across it as well.

Comment: Like CoAstroGeek said, if that wall shown in blue is load bearing, there has to be an equivalent load bearing member (beam, or header) that bridges what looks like a closet over to the left hand wall.

Comment: A key to as to whether or not the blue wall is load bearing is to see which way the floor joists run on the second floor, which is what the first floor ceiling is attached to.  If they run front to back, then that wall is load bearing.  If they run side to side, then probably not.  What ever you find on the first floor probably applies to the remaining stories.  The roof is a different matter as I'll bet it's a trussed design that only bears on the outer walls, which could be the side walls or the front/back walls, depending on what the roof looks like.

Answer (score 1):

If you are thinking of replacing/removing walls in a home that may or may not be load bearing, consult a structural engineer or an architect. You do not want to make a mistake that you can not correct in removing something that should not be removed without the necessary supports. Once a mistake is made it may be too late to correct that mistake. Just my  2 cents.